# Looping a function over a list in Python

Tags: python, list, function, loops, python-3.x

This Python function interlocks the characters of two words (e.g., "sho" + "col" -> "school"). word1-char1 + word2-char1 + word1-char2 + ...

```
def interlock(a,b):
    i = 0
    c = ""
    d = "" 
    while (i < len(a) and len(b)):
        c = (a[i]+b[i])
        d = d + c
        i+=1
    return(d)

interlock("sho", "col")
```

Now, I would like to apply this function to a list of words. The goal is to find out any interlock corresponds to an item of a list.

```
word_list = ["test", "col", "tele", "school", "tel", "sho", "aye"]
```

To do that, I would first have to create a new list that has all the interlocks in it. This is exactly where I am stuck - I don't know how to iterate over word_list using interlock.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `i < len(a) and len(b)` means `(i < len(a)) and len(b)`

Comment: are `test-col` and `col-test` valid pairings or do you only pair once?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: test-col and col-test are  both not valid. E.g.,

test + col -> tceoslt : invalid // 
test + tele -> tteeslte : invalid // 
col + test -> ctoelst : invalid // 
sho + col -> school : valid

Comment: but they both appear in the list? I am talking about combinations to pass to interlock

Comment: interlock is applied to individual character of the words, not the words. thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler - that's what it is supposed to mean. thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? `len(b)` is True unless `b` is empty string. I think you mean `i < len(a) and i < len(b)`. Hint `for i,j in zip(a, b):` might be an easier approach

Comment: What you call "interlocking" is commonly called "zipping". The Python `zip` function can be used here, e.g. `''.join((t[0] + t[1] for t in zip("sho", "col")))` yields `school`.

Comment: Or even shorter: `''.join(sum(zip(a,b), tuple()))`, or `''.join(map(''.join,zip(a,b)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all possible permutations of the list to pass to interlock without pairing a word with itself  i.e we won't get `interlock("col", "col")`:

```
def interlock(s1,s2):
    out = ""
    while s1 and s2: # keep looping until any string is empty
        out += s1[0] + s2[0]
        s1, s2 = s1[1:], s2[1:]
    return out +  s1 + s2 # add the remainder of any longer string

word_list = ["test", "col", "tele", "school", "tel", "sho","col" "aye"]

from itertools import permutations 
# get all permutations of len 2 from our word list
perms = permutations(word_list,2)

st = set(word_list)
for a, b in perms:
    res = interlock(a,b)
    if res in st:
        print(res)
school
```

You can also achieve the same result using [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) using a fillvalue of `""` to catch the end of the longer words:

```
from itertools import permutations, zip_longest

perms = permutations(word_list, 2)

st = set(word_list)
for a, b in perms:
    res = "".join("".join(tup) for tup in zip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=""))
    if res in st:
        print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using product function from itertools module:

```
from itertools import product

for a, b in product(word_list, word_list):
    interlock(a, b)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def interlockList(A):
    while Len(A) > 2:
      B = interlock(A[0],A[1])
      A.remove(A[0])
      A.remove(A[1])
      A.insert(0, B)
    return B
```

Comment: c = (a[i]+b[i])
IndexError: string index out of range -> basically, my function only works if all the strings have the same number of characters